# Does GNU Makefile support shell parameter expansion like "path/{a, b}"?

Tags: linux, makefile

I am writing Makefile dist and install target. There are many files to copy. So i want to know whether gnu make support parameter like shell'.

**In makefile**, I want to something achieve this below.

```
cp src/server/{IPinfo_server, IPinfo_server.conf} IPinfo/server
```

Now i write like this below **in makefile**.

```
cp src/server/IPinfo_server IPinfo/server
cp src/server/IPinfo_server.conf IPinfo/server
```

Or may be i should write it in shell script?

PS: I tried to google it. But i don't know how to describe the question. :-(

**PS1: The problem is there should not space in  "IPinfo_server, IPinfo_server.conf"**

Comment: Please describe it better here too. What do you want to achieve?

Comment: @DidierTrosset updated it :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it does.

It's easy to test out.

```
$ cat GNUmakefile

all: 
    @echo foo{1,2}

$ gmake
foo1 foo2

$ echo $SHELL
/bin/bash
```

In case it doesn't work for you, try explicitly adding `SHELL = /bin/bash` to your GNUMakefile.

Comment: Thanks, i find out the problem. It is because the blank space between the comma and IPinfo_server.conf.

Comment: +1, but I think it is wrong to say that Make supports it.  Make is totally oblivious, and is just passing the text straight through to the shell.